# How to use streaming video in moodle 2.2

Tags: red5, moodle

I used Moodle 2.2. I have a video streaming server is used to Red5. I want to use this server to play the video on moodle.

In moodle 1.9, i found WebClass plugin for streaming video on Moodle from red5 server.
But moodle 2.2, I have not found any solution?

How to use streaming video in moodle 2.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://moodle.org/plugins/pluginversions.php?plugin=mod_livestreaming

Answer (score 0):

You can also use big blue button, that uses red5, an it has plugin for moodle

Answer (score 0):

or alternatively: http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/MoodlePlugin.html